# Clickonce deployment security issue

Tags: dns, active-directory, clickonce

We have created a dns for external and internal employees to visit an application website. They can both reach the website hosted in iis. they can both download the application that has been deployed using clickonce.

Issue is we want to password protect for external employees.. Internally its ok because we use windows authentication and have a group of users for specific applications.

we created an ad account and password. when i setup windows auth and restrict to this one ad account. i enter in username and password when going to the external dns. thats fine.. i click on the application to install.. and when its trying to install i get + The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.i'm getting a security error even after i put in the credentials , it somehow still fails when going to install.. what can i do to better password protect applications that will be accessed from the outside using clickonce.. or fix this issue thanks